# How do I get an Django ViewSet to return a 403 error on anonymous post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get my app to return a 403 error when an anonymous user attempts to POST to it. Right now it returns a 201 code, but doesn't save the post to the database.

The problem is that my unit test fails because it's checking for a 403 code.

Here is my views

```
from post.models import Post
from post.serializers import PostSerializer
from post.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrAdmin
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    # The default will be that anyone can read a post, but only owners can change it
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)

    def get_permissions(self):
        # Both owners and admins can destroy a post, so if we're destroying we change permissions
        if self.action in ('destroy',):
            self.permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrAdmin, ]
        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
        else:
            return Response('Cannot post anonymously', status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

You can see I'm checking if the user is authenticated and if not, return a Response with a 403 code, but for some reason a 201 code is being returned.

How do I get it to return a 403 code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to send a response from `perform_create`, but this can't be done. You see, DRF (Django REST Framework) doesn't call the `perform_create` method in a *straight-forward* manner. What happens is that DRF first calls [`CreateModelMixin`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin)'s `create` method. Which then calls the `perform_create` method and then returns the response.

In, short, the response is returned by the `create` method, not `perform_create` method. And the `create` method, by default, returns the `201` status code (or sometimes `400`).

So, you will need to override the `create` method instead. First, take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L18-L23) for this method. Now, override:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        self.perform_create(serializer)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied('Cannot post anonymously')

    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: @MatthewDrill The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#permissiondenied) says it returns the response with 403 status code. Do you think you're using a middleware which is changing the response status codes?

Comment: not that I know of. I can show you the MIDDLEWARE variable in my settings.py `MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]`

Comment: @MatthewDrill I've updated the answer. See if it's any help now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using return, use raise.

raise PermissionDenied